# Wake on Lan: cannot enable

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wake-on-lan

I am trying to set up wake on lan on my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop.

I have (as far as I know) enabled the feature in the BIOS.

The interface details are

```
user@pc:~$ sudo ethtool enp6s0
Settings for enp6s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: d
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x000060e4 (24804)
                   link ifup rx_err tx_err hw wol
    Link detected: no
```

The line `Wake-on: d` suggests to me that the feature is available.

However, the following happens when tring to enable magic packages:

```
sudo ethtool -s enp6s0 wol g
Cannot set new wake-on-lan settings: Operation not supported
  not setting wol
```

Any ideas what is happening here? Thanks.

Comment: I think the "Supports Wake-on: d" says that it doesn't support WoL. It should say something like "pumbag" rather than "d" to list the supported options. I suggest another trip to the BIOS to see if there is some option you have missed.

Comment: Thanks @icarus. I'll look through the settings again. There is no explicit option and I assumed it's enabled by default as suggested by this article https://www.gigabyte.ru/microsites/91

Comment: Sorry, my russion is a bit russty.  The motherboard manual says:  ErP
 When this item is set to Enabled, the following functions will become unavailable: PME event wake up, power on by mouse, power on by keyboard, and wake on LAN.  On the russian site, the image shows ErP disabled.

Comment: I've checked that ErP is disabled. I'm not sure what else to try... maybe update the bios.